# Maximizing the variance of weights of Bernoulli RV maximize mutual information?

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, information-theory, mutual-information

I have a random variable $X=a_1X_1+a_2X_2 + \ldots a_kX_k$ where $X_i \sim Bern(q)$,  $X_i \perp X_j, \forall i,j\in \{1,2\ldots,k\}$. Also $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i=k$ and  $a_i \in  \mathbb{N} \bigcup \{0\}$ (Non-negative integers).

In essence, $X$ is a discrete random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2\ldots,k\}$ which is the weighted sum of up to $k$ IID Bernoulli random variables.

I have another Binary random variable $Y$  such that $Y=0$ with probability $\frac{0.1}{1+x}$ when $X=x$. Note that the transition probabilities $\frac{0.1}{1+x}$ is decreasing in $x$.

**I have a conjecture that the mutual information $I(X ; Y)$ is maximum when $Var(a_{i})$  or equivalently $\sum a_i^2$ is maximum. Moreover, in general, $I(X ; Y)$  increases as $\sum a_i^2$ increases.**

Can someone help me verify if this is correct and establish this formally?

Comment: As stated, $X$ does not take values in $\{0,1,2\ldots,k\}$

Comment: Take $k=2$  $a=(1.1, 0.9)$ Then $X$ takes values on $\{ 0, 0.9 , 1.1 , 2\}$

Comment: @leonbloy $a_i$ belongs to set of non-negative integers.

Comment: Ah, I missed that